# Dependency injection on abstract constructor

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, abstract-class, abstract

```
class Test {
  function test()
  {
      return 'test';
  }
}


abstract class MasterAbstract {

    public function __construct (Test $test)
    {
        $this->test = test;
    }

    protected function runMaster()
    {
        return $this->test->test();
    }

}

class Child extends MasterAbstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        return 1212;
    }
}
```

Case 1:

```
$c = new Child();
echo $c->run;
```

Getting error here

> Argument 1 passed to MasterAbstract::__construct() must be an instance
>   of Test, none given

Case 2: In this i'm not creating any object for the child or someotherController. It's working . I'm using laravel framework

```
class SomeotherController 
 {
    private $ch;

    public function __constructor(Child $ch)
    {
       $this->ch = $ch;
    }

    public function run()
    {
       return $this->ch->run();
    }
 }
```

Please anyone explain how these two case working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case #2 You injects `Child` object class with constructor's parameter which is resolved by [Laravel's IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container)

In case #1 You create `Child` object with `new` statment and You need to give a `Test` class in the parameter.

If You want to go like this You cal call the app container make method:

```
$c = app(Child::class);
echo $c->run;
```

The `app(Child::class)` is the same as `\App::make(Child::class)`. It gives You new object's instance and automaticly resolves the dependencies.